# SSAS 2008 tutorial

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2008

Can anyone tell me the site for getting SSAS 2008 and SSRS 2008 tutorial ? In PDF file if possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this sounds obvious, but have you tried using the help in SSRS/SSAS? There should be tutorials available from the contents page.

Answer (score 2):

I have written 3 books on SQL Server BI (for both 2005 and 2008).  Also, I have a FREE [screencast series on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1C57B4EE4D873A1D&feature=view_all) on how to use SSAS called 'How do I...BI?'

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.learnmicrosoftbi.com/.  There are series of tutorial on SSAS;  need to signup first to download (it's free).

Answer (score -1):

http://pragmaticworks.com/Resources/Default.aspx

They offer free online training / webinars/whitepapers etc etc
 excellent resource for all things BI